# Single Sign-on profile is not working as expected in iPad with Safari

Tags: ios, ipad, safari, single-sign-on, kerberos

I have created Mobileconfig for Single Sign on as recommended @

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html

I was able to deploy the configuration. I attaching the configuration for your reference.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple/DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>PayloadContent</key>
    <array>
      <dict>
        <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
        <string>mycompany SSO Settings</string>
        <key>PayloadType</key>
        <string>com.apple.sso</string>
        <key>PayloadVersion</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>PayloadUUID</key>
        <string>933063A4-DEBC-4CC3-B3A8-EC37C1610D6E</string>
        <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.mycompany.l4-dc.sso</string>
        <key>Name</key>
        <string>L4-DC Domain</string>
        <key>Kerberos</key>
        <dict>
          <key>PrincipalName</key>
          <string>int_5s_admin</string>
          <key>Realm</key>
          <string>l4-dc.com</string>
          <key>URLPrefixMatches</key>
          <array>
            <string>http://ix-2k12r2-web.l4-dc.com/</string>
          </array>
          <key>AppIdentifierMatches</key>
          <array>
            <string>com.apple.mobilesafari</string>
          </array>
        </dict>
      </dict>
    </array>
    <key>PayloadOrganization</key>
    <string>mycompany</string>
    <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
    <string>SSO for mycompany</string>
    <key>PayloadVersion</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
    <key>PayloadUUID</key>
    <string>70752C93-582B-4B82-AA18-BCE31C39BD75</string>
    <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.mycompany.l4-dc.sso.profile</string>
    <key>PayloadDescription</key>
    <string>mycompany SSO Configuration profile</string>
    <key>PayloadType</key>
    <string>Configuration</string>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

When I access the website from browser, single sign-on password dialog comes three time and normal safari windows authentication dialog comes three times and web application is not loaded.

Based on IIS logs, I understand that there was no credentials passed from safari to the server and IIS was issuing 401 challenge.

**Background:**

*Back End Server:*
Windows Server 2012 R2, IIS 8.5, Integrated Windows Authentication

*Front End:*
iPad, iOS 8.4 & above, Safari Browser

Web Application is typical ASP.NET MVC application and works fine with NTLM and stops working from Safari after deploying Single Sign-on profile.

Regards,
Madhan

Answer (score 1):

After debugging issue, following are the items which needs to be take care.

1) In Windows Environment, proper SPN registration for the server should be taken care.
2) IIS Server Should be enabled with Kerberos based Authentication for the Web Application

After cross checking and fixing the issues related to above two items, configuration started working as expected.